# Using a Windows forms Textbox control in an XNA game

Tags: xna-4.0, windows, control

What I want to do is this: Use a standard Textbox control in an XNA game. This will be the only control used, and the game is designed in xna alone. I (for some reason) cannot get the game to "see" the System.Drawing assembly in the program. I have added the needed reference, but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a Textbox control in XNA, as XNA doesn't support drawing Windows Forms.  You will need to write your own Textbox control in XNA, or use one of the freely available XNA control libraries that people have made available online.